# C++ error: Variable does not name a type when attemtping to access global variables

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, header-files

Within a program i am writing i have 3 files. main, functions and a header file. The main file makes use of the header #include "implementation.cpp", and the function file makes use of the header #include "driver.h". Within the implementation file 3 structs have been declared, each sharing their values through the use of extern, too be seen in the minimal reproducing code required. Within the header file i have declared 3 variables to use these extern variables. I believed this was enough to fix my issue but problem still aries. When my code attempts to compile i recieve the following error messages. There are alot but I believe they all stem from the same issue. That issue being the header file able to locate the types Customer, Parts and Builder

```
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:7:1: error: 'Customer' does not name a type
    7 | Customer myCustomer;
      | ^~~~~~~~
driver.h:8:1: error: 'Builder' does not name a type
    8 | Builder myBuilder;
      | ^~~~~~~
driver.h:9:1: error: 'Part' does not name a type
    9 | Part myPart;
      | ^~~~
driver.h:14:13: error: 'Part' was not declared in this scope
   14 | std::vector<Part> readpartFile();
      |             ^~~~
driver.h:14:17: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   14 | std::vector<Part> readpartFile();
      |                 ^
driver.h:14:17: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:16:13: error: 'Customer' was not declared in this scope
   16 | std::vector<Customer> readcustomerFile();
      |             ^~~~~~~~
driver.h:16:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   16 | std::vector<Customer> readcustomerFile();
      |                     ^
driver.h:16:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:18:13: error: 'Builder' was not declared in this scope
   18 | std::vector<Builder> readbuilderFile();
      |             ^~~~~~~
driver.h:18:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   18 | std::vector<Builder> readbuilderFile();
      |                    ^
driver.h:18:20: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:20:24: error: 'Customer' does not name a type
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~
driver.h:20:55: error: 'Part' was not declared in this scope
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                                                       ^~~~
driver.h:20:59: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                                                           ^
driver.h:20:59: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:22:40: error: 'Part' was not declared in this scope
   22 | void robotComplexity(const std::vector<Part>& vecB, const std::vector<Customer>& vecC);
      |                                        ^~~~
driver.h:22:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   22 | void robotComplexity(const std::vector<Part>& vecB, const std::vector<Customer>& vecC);
      |                                            ^
driver.h:22:44: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:22:71: error: 'Customer' was not declared in this scope
   22 | void robotComplexity(const std::vector<Part>& vecB, const std::vector<Customer>& vecC);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~
driver.h:22:79: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   22 | void robotComplexity(const std::vector<Part>& vecB, const std::vector<Customer>& vecC);
      |                                                                               ^
driver.h:22:79: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:24:38: error: 'Customer' was not declared in this scope
   24 | double variability(const std::vector<Customer>& customerList, const std::vector<Builder>& builderList);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~
driver.h:24:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   24 | double variability(const std::vector<Customer>& customerList, const std::vector<Builder>& builderList);
      |                                              ^
driver.h:24:46: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:24:81: error: 'Builder' was not declared in this scope
   24 | double variability(const std::vector<Customer>& customerList, const std::vector<Builder>& builderList);
      |                                                                                 ^~~~~~~
driver.h:24:88: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   24 | double variability(const std::vector<Customer>& customerList, const std::vector<Builder>& builderList);
      |                                                                                        ^
driver.h:24:88: error: template argument 2 is invalid
driver.h:26:34: error: 'Builder' was not declared in this scope
   26 | std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~
driver.h:26:45: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
   26 | std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot);
      |                                             ^~~~~~
driver.h:26:65: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
   26 | std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot);
      |                                                                 ^~~~~~
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:43:19: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'std::vector<Part> readpartFile()'
   43 | std::vector<Part> readpartFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:14:19: note: old declaration 'int readpartFile()'
   14 | std::vector<Part> readpartFile();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:77:23: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'std::vector<Customer> readcustomerFile()'
   77 | std::vector<Customer> readcustomerFile()
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:16:23: note: old declaration 'int readcustomerFile()'
   16 | std::vector<Customer> readcustomerFile();
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:100:22: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'std::vector<Builder> readbuilderFile()'
  100 | std::vector<Builder> readbuilderFile()
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:18:22: note: old declaration 'int readbuilderFile()'
   18 | std::vector<Builder> readbuilderFile();
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:208:81: error: 'std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder, double, double)' redeclared as different kind of entity
  208 | vector<double>buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot) {
      |                                                                                 ^
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:26:21: note: previous declaration 'std::vector<double> buildAttempt'
   26 | std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder b, double variaiblity, double complexityRobot);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp: In function 'std::vector<double> buildAttempt(Builder, double, double)':
implementation.cpp:230:23: error: no matching function for call to 'complexity(Customer&, int&)'
  230 |  complexity(c,partsVec);
      |                       ^
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:20:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const int&, const int&)'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
driver.h:20:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Customer' to 'const int&'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:138:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const Customer&, const std::vector<Part>&)'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
implementation.cpp:138:62: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<Part>&'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
implementation.cpp:243:23: error: no matching function for call to 'complexity(Customer&, int&)'
  243 |  complexity(c,partsVec);
      |                       ^
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:20:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const int&, const int&)'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
driver.h:20:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Customer' to 'const int&'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:138:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const Customer&, const std::vector<Part>&)'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
implementation.cpp:138:62: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<Part>&'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
driver.cpp: In function 'int main()':
driver.cpp:24:27: error: no matching function for call to 'complexity(Customer&, int&)'
   24 |     complexity(c, partsVec);
      |                           ^
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:20:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const int&, const int&)'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
driver.h:20:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Customer' to 'const int&'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:138:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const Customer&, const std::vector<Part>&)'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
implementation.cpp:138:62: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<Part>&'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
driver.cpp:26:53: error: no matching function for call to 'complexity(Customer&, int&)'
   26 |     writeFile(buildAttempt(b, complexity(c, partsVec), variability(customerVec, builderVec)));
      |                                                     ^
In file included from implementation.cpp:8,
                 from driver.cpp:4:
driver.h:20:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const int&, const int&)'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
driver.h:20:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Customer' to 'const int&'
   20 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from driver.cpp:4:
implementation.cpp:138:7: note: candidate: 'float complexity(const Customer&, const std::vector<Part>&)'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
implementation.cpp:138:62: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<Part>&'
  138 | float complexity(const Customer& c, const std::vector<Part>& parts)
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Below is the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce this error. For convience i am only going to include code relevent to Part, as the base code for customer and builder is the same

my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "implementation.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector> 
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Part p;
    auto partsVec =  readpartFile();return 0;
}
```

my header file

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE
#define SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE


std::vector<Part> readpartFile();

#endif
```

From this point it is noted that the program does not recongise Part myPart, therefore declaring the vector as type Part does not work. Due to this these errors occur.

```
driver.h:9:1: error: 'Part' does not name a type
    9 | Part myPart;
      | ^~~~
driver.h:14:13: error: 'Part' was not declared in this scope
   14 | std::vector<Part> readpartFile();
      |             ^~~~
```

Finally here is the implementation file with code relevent to Part

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include "driver.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct Part {
char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;
};
extern Part myPart;

std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");


std::vector<Part> readpartFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
    std::vector<Part> parts;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(partsList, line))
    {
        line.pop_back(); //removing '.' at end of line
        std::string token;
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        Part part;

        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.partCode = token[0];
        std::getline(ss, part.partName, ':');
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.minimum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.maximum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.complexity = std::stoi(token);
        parts.push_back(std::move(part));
    }

    return parts;
    }
```

This code shuould be enough to provide anyone with the means to find out my issue and possible rectify the issue. Thankyou

P.S it should be noted that I have tried putting my structs in my header file, which does not work.

Comment: Don't `#include "implementation.cpp"`. Include header files, compile `.cpp` files. Your header file is also missing an include guard just as in your last question.

Comment: is this a fix for my code or is this a comment on makiing the quesiton easier to understand?

Comment: It's a comment regarding all c++ code you'll probably ever need to write. Header files contains class definitions and function declarations etc. and `.cpp` files contains function definitions as your `readpartFile()` implementation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo inregards to include guard, please see my updated quesiton regarding my header file. Ive updated it using guards

Comment: The include guard looks ok but should be before including the other headers and just remember that all identifiers regardless of use that begin with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved names. You need to split your header/code up differently. You have again a global variable in your header file and you use your `.cpp` as a header file too. Move the `struct Part` definition to a header file. Move declaration of global variables to a `.cpp` file (that you compile, not include).

Comment: the use guard does not work.

Comment: Do you want a global variable named `myPart` ? It's a bad idea in most cases. Further, I can't see that you use it at all...

Comment: @4386427 yes sorry i meant to remove this.

Comment: You're just breaking all the rules. **Don't** include cpp files. **Don't** define global variables in header file (still you are doing this). **Do** put class declarations in headers (you've moved it to a cpp file for some reason). It goes on, I don't know what to suggest. The code you have now is completely different from what I said in your previous question. I don;t know why you aren't following what I said.

Comment: @john I think maybe you are trying to follow suggestions (I hope you are) but getting it slightly wrong for some reason. If that happens you should ask again, because I think you must be trying to fix things yourself based on an incorrect understanding and just making things worse. Or you could try and read some tutorial that explains these rules so that you **understand** what you are doing, instead of just trying to follow suggestions.

Comment: One of my class mates was assisting me, but due to his advanced udnerstanding i got lost in his explainations of things

Comment: Being able to manage header files and source files in a program with more than one file is something that many newbies stumble on. But it's not a difficult thing to get right, it's not a mystery. You just need to take some time, do some studying, and learn what the issues are and how they get solved. Really any decent C++ tutorial or book will cover this important but basic topic.

Comment: Ive definently learn alot from the questions I have posted today. I thank everyone thats contributed and helped me along the way. Really appreciate it. C++ is a bit tough for me i wont lie but im tryingg my best

Comment: @DavidLing You are welcome. The question is still listed as unanswered though. Didn't any/all of the answer(s) help you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You header file should look like this

```
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE
#define SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE

#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Part {
    char partCode;
    std::string partName;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
    int complexity;

};
extern Part myPart;

std::vector<Part> readpartFile();

#endif
```

Your main file should look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector> 
#include <random>
#include "myheaderfile.h" // sorry I don't know what your header file is really called
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Part p;
    auto partsVec =  readpartFile();return 0;
}
```

Your implementation file should look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include "myheaderfile.h" // sorry I don't know what your header file is really called
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

std::vector<Part> readpartFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
    std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Restructured.

driver.h

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Part {                      // class definition
    char partCode;
    std::string partName;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
    int complexity;
};

std::vector<Part> readpartFile();  // (extern) forward declaration of a function

#endif
```

implementation.cpp

```
// only include what you use:

#include "driver.h"

//#include <algorithm>  // why?
#include <fstream>
//#include <iostream>   // why?
//#include <random>     // why?
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//#include <time.h>     // why?

// using namespace std; // don't

std::vector<Part>
readpartFile() // function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
    std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt"); // don't make this global
    std::vector<Part> parts;
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(partsList, line)) {
        line.pop_back(); // removing '.' at end of line
        std::string token;
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        Part part;

        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.partCode = token[0];
        std::getline(ss, part.partName, ':');
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.minimum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.maximum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.complexity = std::stoi(token);
        parts.push_back(std::move(part));
    }

    return parts;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "driver.h" // not implementation.cpp

// unused header files removed

int main() {
    Part p;
    auto partsVec = readpartFile();
}
```

Compile - no header files, only `.cpp` files:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors main.cpp implementation.cpp -o program
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a number of misunderstandings in releation to what you put in cpp-files and what you put in header files.

But to start with - don't include cpp files! It's the header file that you shall include.

So do

```
#include "implementation.h"  // instead of implementation.cpp
```

The implementation.h must have the definition of the `Part` struct. So move it from the cpp file to the header file. Like:

**implementation.h**

```
#ifndef SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE
#define SOME_UNIQUE_NAME_HERE

#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Part {
    char partCode;
    std::string partName;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
    int complexity;
};


std::vector<Part> readpartFile();

#endif
```

And then you include the header file in implementation.cpp

**implementation.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include "driver.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

#include "implementation.h"  // Notice

using namespace std;


std::vector<Part> readpartFile() 
{
    ...
}
```

and likewise you include it in other files that needs to use the struct `Part`

Comment: This whole story started because the OP had some global variables defined in a header file (see `myPart` above). Maybe you could extend this answer to show the correct way to declare and define that global variable.

Comment: @john well, OP says in a comment that the `myPart` was to be removed - and OP have done that now. So I think my answer would be strange if I write about `myPart`

Comment: @john also, there 3 answers now - all with good information - so OP should be able to fix the problem now,

Comment: You maybe right, but in an earlier question he said that the global variables were essential to the working of the program. Something about the driver code needed them. Oh well.